# Form is submitting even after failing Javascript validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, submit

I have a form called here:

```
<span class="aligncenter button"><a href="#" onclick="submitForm('newIncident');">Submit</a></span>
```

And I have a JavaScript function here:

```
if (myForm == 'newIncident')
    {
        var vDemAge = document.forms['newIncident']['demAge'].value;
        var vBibNumber = document.forms['newIncident']['bibNumber'].value;

        // Run through validations before submitting form
        validateTime();
        validateDate();
        validateAge();
        validateGender();
        validateLocation();
        validateType();
        validateDisposition();

        if (vDemAge == 'Age' || vDemAge == '')   // If Age is not entered, set the value to be blank
            {
                document.forms['newIncident']['demAge'].value = '';
            }
        if (vBibNumber == 'Bib #' || vBibNumber == '')  // If Bib # is not entered, set the value to blank
            {
                document.forms['newIncident']['bibNumber'].value = '';
            }
        document.getElementById(myForm).submit();
    }
else
    {
        document.getElementById(myForm).submit();
    }
```

So I have each of the validations as a separate function that I am calling in sequence when submitting the form.  If I comment out the "document.getElementById(myForm).submit();", the validations run as expected.  However, if I leave it uncommented, it submits every time even if the validations fail.  How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks!

EDIT:
So this is one of the validations I'm running.  They're all structured the same way.  Somewhere I should be returning a boolean true/false?  How exactly would I insert that in this one below?

```
function validateDisposition()
{
    var vIncidentDisposition = document.forms['newIncident']['incidentDisposition'].value;
    if (vIncidentDisposition == '')
        {
            document.forms['newIncident']['incidentDisposition'].className = 'required';
        }
    else
        {
            document.forms['newIncident']['incidentDisposition'].className = 'formborder';
        }
}
```

Comment: can you show some of the validation function as well?

Comment: Where are you telling the form NOT to submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your validation functions return a bool, you should have something like

```
if( validateTime() && validateDate() && validateAge()... etc ) {
    if (vDemAge == 'Age' || vDemAge == '')   // If Age is not entered, set the value to be blank
        {
            document.forms['newIncident']['demAge'].value = '';
        }
    if (vBibNumber == 'Bib #' || vBibNumber == '')  // If Bib # is not entered, set the value to blank
        {
            document.forms['newIncident']['bibNumber'].value = '';
        }
    document.getElementById(myForm).submit();
}
```

Comment: yeah, that is my suspicion. They probably think the "return false" from the other validations will stop the higher level function from running too, which isn't the case

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!  The boolean idea put me on the right path.  Thanks!

I just added a "return true" and "return false" to each of the validations, then used the answer above with the "&&" if to build the logic into the myform "if".  If it doesn't pass all of them the else does a "return false".  Works like a charm!